# How to fix issue with .htaccess mod_rewrite and trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess `mod_rewrite` for nicer URLs.

Here is a part of my .htaccess file that turns `/artist.php?id=123456` into `/artist/123456`, `/artists.php?culture=arabic` into `/artists/arabic`, and removes the .php:

```
RewriteRule ^artist/([0-9]+) artist.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^artists/(.+) artists.php?culture=$1
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works, but if I put a trailing slash `/` at the end like `/artist/arabic/` it throws a 404 error. How can I fix this? Simply removing the trailing slash would probably work but I don't know how to do that with this. I just don't want a user to accidentally add a `/` or something and then get confused thinking the page doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add an optional trailing slash into the first rule with `/?`

```
# Optional trailing slash...
RewriteRule ^artist/([0-9]+)/? artist.php?id=$1
#--------------------------^^^^
RewriteRule ^artists/(.+) artists.php?culture=$1
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. And surprisingly it works for another directory's .htaccess file (it added the optional / without actually putting the rule in it... is that how it is supposed to work when you put it in the first rule?)

Comment: Oh,  that is because the [L]  flag was left off,  causing it to fall through to the next match.  You usually won't want that, and I unintentionally left it out of my answer.